# How do I create partitioned table based on timestamp column in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

In the following table there is only two columns(ts and transaction_id) and 3 rows. I just tried to create a partitioned table based on timestamp column but I get error message.

```
create table myfirstdataset.partition_table1(ts timestamp, transaction_id int64)partition by ts as
select timestamp '2013-12-31 01:55:02.000 UTC' ts, 10 transaction_id union all
select timestamp '2013-12-31 02:10:02.000 UTC' ts, 5 transaction_id union all
select timestamp '2013-12-31 04:20:02.000 UTC' ts, 6 transaction_id 

Error: PARTITION BY expression must be DATE(<timestamp_column>) or else a DATE column
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [CREATE TABLE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#create_table_statement)? Was something unclear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be `PARTITION BY DATE(ts)` instead of `PARTITION BY ts` - see [`CREATE TABLE statement`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#create_table_statement)  and [`partition_expression`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#partition_expression) in particular

```
create table myfirstdataset.partition_table1(ts timestamp, transaction_id int64)partition by date(ts) as
select timestamp '2013-12-31 01:55:02.000 UTC' ts, 10 transaction_id union all
select timestamp '2013-12-31 02:10:02.000 UTC' ts, 5 transaction_id union all
select timestamp '2013-12-31 04:20:02.000 UTC' ts, 6 transaction_id
```

Answer (score 0):

create or replace table stage_pcm_dev.tab1(forecast_date date) as select forecast_date from `bigquery-public-data.covid19_public_forecasts.county_14d`